# PHP keeps escaping my form's input (adding \ behind my ')

Tags: php, escaping, magic-quotes

So basically when I type something with an apostrophe, such as John's bike it will echo John\'s bike. The code below:

```
<?php
$searchname = $_POST["name"] ;
echo "$searchname";
```

My form uses the POST method. Is there any way to stop this?

Also to make input case insensitive how would I go about in this segment?

```
$searchsport = $_POST['sport'];
$sportarray = array(
"Football" => "Fb01",
"Cricket" => "ck32",
"Tennis" => "Tn43",
);
if(isset($sportarray[$searchsport])){
header("Location: ".$sportarray[$searchsport].".html");
die;
}
    //what code is needed to make the if statement work? I've looked up some weird ways such as using array_change_key_case (which I clearly don't understand).
```

Comment: Also is there a tool to make php (or any code) to compress into a single line? i.e. make it hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely because you have **[magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)** turned on, try this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  $searchname = stripslashes($_POST["name"]);
  echo "$searchname";
}
else
{
  $searchname = $_POST["name"];
  echo "$searchname";
}
```

In fact, you could create a function instead to do it automatically for you:

```
function fixIt($str)
{
    if (is_array($str))
    {
        foreach ($str as &$value)
        {
            $value = fixIt($value);
        }

        return $str;
    }
    else
    {
        return stripslashes($str);
    }    
}
```

And then you can simply do:

```
$searchname = fixIt($_POST["name"]);
echo $searchname;
```

**Note:** You can also disable the ugly magic quotes from php.ini as they are problematic and rightly deprecated and out of the future versions of PHP.

Comment: Beware, you will not be able to ever use an array in a form with this method.

Comment: @ircmaxell: That is rightly pointed, did not pay attention to array. Thanks

Comment: Cool, do you know if there is something like the stripslashes function but makes my input case insensitive? I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: @Haskella: Could you be more specific, what do you want?

Comment: Hrm, do you remember my sports search bar? The code only made things accept exact spelling (i.e. case sensitive), is there a php method employed to make it insensitive? Hope I'm making sense :S

Comment: @Haskella: There are functions for case insenstive such as `str_ireplace`, `eregi`, and more. It just depends what you want to do and which function you have to use.

Comment: I did a little googling and eregi seems to be the one, but unfortunately it has been deprecated...

Comment: @Haskella: if you want to **replace**, you can use `str_ireplace` or `pre_replace` for regular expression replace with `/i` modifier for case insensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways.

1. Turn off [magic_quotes_gpc](http://us.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) in php.ini

   ```
   magic_quotes_gpc = 0
   ```
2. In the beginning of the request, run stripslashes

   ```
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() && !function_exists('FixMagicQuotesGpc')) {
       function FixMagicQuotesGpc($data) {
           if (is_array($data)) {
               foreach ($data as &$value) {
                   $value = FixMagicQuotesGpc($value);
               }
               return $data;
           } else {
               return stripslashes($data);
           }
       }
       $_GET = FixMagicQuotesGpc($_GET);
       $_POST = FixMagicQuotesGpc($_POST);
       $_REQUEST = FixMagicQuotesGpc($_REQUEST);
   }
   ```

EDIT:  Added the !function_exists part.  This way, you don't need to worry if you ran it before, it'll just skip it if it's already been run (by another file, etc)

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it, actually! :)

Comment: I haven't learnt enough php or programming, rather to understand functions fully =/ but I appreciate your effort in coming back to edit it, thanks (too bad I can't give out two answers) :D
I hope someone will find this code helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) configuration variable. It really is annoying (and deprecated!).

You should turn it off in `php.ini`, or ask your web host if they can do something about it.

If they can't, you can use [`addslashes`](https://www.php.net/addslashes) and [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) to manually escape/un-escape. Beware, though - you should use something more secure than `addslashes` for submitting to a database. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is a better option, or the function specific to your database:

- `mysqli_escape_string`
- `sqlite_escape_string`
- [a bigger list](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=escape_string&lang=en)

Comment: I know what you mean. :) OK. A lot of hosts keep it on for compatibility, annoyingly.

Answer (score 0):

I include the following script within my config file to fix magic quotes if necessary.  That way I don't have to worry about the magic quotes settings of the host.

```
<?php

set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

function _remove_magic_quotes(&$input) {
    if(is_array($input)) {
        foreach(array_keys($input) as $key) _remove_magic_quotes($input[$key]);
    }
    else $input = stripslashes($input);
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    _remove_magic_quotes($_REQUEST);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_GET);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_POST);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_COOKIE);
}

return true;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic Quotes... I'll be so happy when PHP 6 finally arrives and removes this monster of incompatibility.

The best solution is to turn it off in php.ini by setting

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

If you don't have access to php.ini but are using Apache, you can also disable it in an `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

The last ditch scenario is to disable it in your application.  the PHP Manual's [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) page suggests using this:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```